# How can I add type declarations to a local non-JavaScript file?

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

I have a plugin for my bundler (in my case [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)), that loads files, that are neither JS nor TS (the plugins simply transforms the file to valid JavaScript on import).

I want to provide typescript declarations for those non-JavaScript files.

#### Things I have already tried / considered

###### Wildcard module declarations

*[As described here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations)*
I could go with a similar approach to what Vue does for example:

```ts
declare module '*.vue' {
   export default MyFancyType;
}
```

This does not work for me, because all files have different contents and should therefore have different types.

###### Using `declare module` with paths

I have also tried using `declare module` with a relative and absolute path of the file.
This won't work for two reasons:

1. TS errors with *Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module name.*
2. Relative paths won't work anyways, because I could have imports from multiple TS files with different relative paths.

###### Adding a `myfile.ext.d.ts` file next to the imported file

This works in theory, but in my case that would mean A LOT of files. So this is undesirable.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution better then `myfile.ext.d.ts`. Why exactly is "a lot of files" being bad?

Comment: It just gets quite messy quite fast. Also it’s hard to keep track which files were generated automatically. Adding it to the `.gitignore` helps, but it’s just not a perfect solution for my use case :(

Comment: do you need to `import` them or could use a typed `myImport` function?

Comment: @Dimava could you please elaborate? 
I don't quite understand what you mean by _"a typed `myImport` function"_.

Comment: function myImport(s: 'a' | 'b') { if (s=='a')return import('a'); else return import('b') }

Comment: That is a actually a good idea but that doesn’t really work for my use case, because of how I want the vite plugin to work. The core concept is that you can import the files directly without any extra steps or setup.